# Highlight a square on a checker board when mouse is over

Tags: javascript

ive drawn a checker board on a canvas and i want to highlight the square which the mouse is over. I have given it a go but the furthest i can get is with it half a square out of sync.

Here is my code:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt)
{
    const position = getGridPoint(evt);

    drawBoard(); //Clears the last highlight

    context.lineWidth='3'; //Draws the new highlight
    context.strokeStyle = 'yellow';
    context.rect(position.x * board.squareW, position.y * board.squareH, board.squareW, board.squareH);
    context.stroke();
})

function getGridPoint(evt)
{
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    //board.w = width of the board
    //board.squareW = width of each tile on the board

    const x = Math.round((evt.clientX - rect.left) / (rect.right - 2 - rect.left) * board.w);
    const y = Math.round((evt.clientY - rect.top) / (rect.bottom - 2 - rect.top) * board.h);

    const roundX = Math.round(x / board.squareW);
    const roundY = Math.round(y / board.squareH);

    return {
        x: roundX,
        y: roundY
    };
}
```

Its something in the 2nd function where im using math.round

So it will work if i manually subtract half a tile's width from x and y but it seems a hacky way and id rather do it properly in the first place

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5toudex0/3/

Comment: Can you post enough code that we can reproduce your problem? Ideally creating a live snippet in your question that can be easily copied to an answer as the basis for providing you an answer.

Comment: You've already got the two things you need. (0) the client co-ord of the mouse cursor and (1) the dimensions of the tiles. Divide the client-pos by the tile-size and you've got your answer. I'll knock together an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this for `getTile`

```
function getTile(evt)
{
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    //board.w = width of the board
    //board.squareW = width of each tile on the board

    const x = Math.floor((evt.clientX - rect.left) / board.squareW);
    const y = Math.floor((evt.clientY - rect.top) / board.squareH);
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little change made to the mousemove handler for the canvas, you can (0) directly get the client position of the mouse and then (1) compute the col/row indices for the tile to highlight.

Consider the following change to your code:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt)
{
    const position = getTile(evt);

  var xPos = evt.clientX, yPos = evt.clientY;
  var xTileIndex = (xPos / board.squareW)>>0;
  var yTileIndex = (yPos / board.squareH)>>0;
  console.log(`x,y = ${xPos},${yPos}`);
  console.log(`x,y = ${xTileIndex},${yTileIndex}`);
```

Comment: thanks enhzflep! another guy posted an answer that works first but i appriciate yours too :) thankyou